# Test platform specific extension code for React Native

Tags: testing, react-native, jestjs

Currently, React Native dynamically requires a file for the running platform with an specific file extension, `*.ios.js` or `*.android.js`. However, when running this code inside a test environment, we get a `require` error because the module `require('./module')` cannot be found in the file tree, which looks like:

- `module.ios.js`
- `module.android.js`

How can we handle this issues in a test environment?

Answer (score 4):

Adding platform specific extensions to `moduleFileExtensions` fixed the problem for me with `jest.14.1`. Credits to : [github link](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native/issues/134#issuecomment-234566808)

Here is a snippet from sample `package.json` which will run all files including scene.jest.js(x).

```json
    "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "preset": "jest-react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "android.js", "ios.js"],
        "testRegex": "\\.scene\\.jest\\.jsx$"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Jest 17.0.0 you can use the `defaultPlatform` configuration for this - see the very bottom of the Jest React Native [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#providesmodule).

As it shows there, you would configure something like this:

```
"haste": {
  "defaultPlatform": "ios",
  "platforms": ["android", "ios"],
},
```

Naturally, this will mean your tests only load the iOS version of your component (or only Android, depending how you choose to configure it).

If you find it important to test both versions, you'll probably need to do something more like the solution mentioned in [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1738) issue, possibly manipulating `Platform.OS` and using `require.requireActual` directly.

(Might also want to track [this](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1370) issue, in case a less hacky solution is eventually found.)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly and maybe there is a better solution but it seems that you can create a `module.js` file that will be used in tests but in platform environment it will still use the `module.ios.js` or `module.android.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom compiler to resolve the platform specific dependencies in your tests. If you are using mocha, this will probably help you:

http://lidatang.com/setup-mocha-testing-react-native/