# Configure Mocha/Babel to resolve React Native platform extensions?

Tags: testing, react-native, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm using Mocha with [react-native-mock](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-mock) to run tests on React Native applications. However, I'm having issues when running tests on components which import platform-specific files, e.g. `require('./MyComponent')` resolves to `MyComponent.android.js` when running on Android. I'd like to be able to configure Mocha or Babel (whichever is appropriate) to be able to resolve these `require`s based on some configuration, e.g. an environment variable.

I'm aware of [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37029998/6362588) which involves adding another file manually, but I'm specifically looking for something that automates this.